# Better sort algorithm for pre-sorted chunks

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a very large list of elements (few millions) which are locally sorted in chunks of variable size.

a b c b i h a j k l e f g a b l...

I know the size, starting and ending position of every chunk in advance.

[a b c] [b i h m] [a j k l] [e f g] [a] [b l] ...

Is there a faster way to sort the list using an algorithm that can make use of the boundary information?

Comment: You could merge sort the arrays in pairs, also what is the algorithm you are trying to be faster than?

Comment: It should be faster than the best algorithm that does not know about the boundaries in the data. Quicksort can be used as a benchmark.

Comment: There is kind of merge sort - **natural** merge sort

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keyword you are looking for is [**k-way/multiway merging**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Way_Merge_Algorithms):
You have k separate sorted lists and want to merge them into a single list of size `n`.

There are two basic approaches that work have similar asymptotic runtime characteristics but work differently in practice:

#### Iterative 2-way merging

(conceptually) builds a balanced binary tree with the lists as leaves and iteratively merges them together until you have only a single list left. This gives you `log k` merge operations (height of the tree) where every merge operation takes time `n`.
This is basically what rakwaht and schnaader described.

#### Direct k-way merging

uses a (binary) heap or a tournament tree to store the smallest element that has not yet been merged for every chunk. Removing the minimum element from this data structure causes the next element from the corresponding chunk to be inserted. So a step of the algorithm takes `O(log k)` and is repeated `n` times, thus giving the same runtime as the iterative binary merge.

Note that the tournament tree approach is more efficient in practice since the traversal of the tournament tree is less data-dependent than the binary heap.

You can also always think about a solution in between these two approaches, like doing 16-way merges, which might be more efficient than one of the two 'extreme' approaches above.

The (iterated) multiway merge approach might seem more complex, however for applications that process huge amounts of data (*external memory* operations which store most of the data on a hard disk), this is much more efficient since much fewer merging steps are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the second phase of a [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) where pairs of sorted sublists are merged together. I would try the following approach:

1. Divide the list into chunks
2. Merge two chunks together with the pseudocode below
3. Repeat step 2 until only one chunk is left, this one is your sorted list

Pseudocode for the merge part:

```
merge(chunk1[], chunk2[], chunk1_length, chunk2_length) {
  chunk1_pointer = chunk2_pointer = 0
  repeat the following:
    compare chunk1[chunk1_pointer] and chunk2[chunk2_pointer]
      same value: add both to the output, increase both pointers
      chunk1 value larger: add chunk2 value to the output, increase chunk2_pointer
      chunk2 value larger: add chunk1 value to the output, increase chunk1_pointer
    is one of the pointers at the end of the chunk?
      add the remaining elements of the other chunk to the output and exit
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Timsort (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) is specifically made for presorted data. 
It tries to find runs in correct order and then merges them.
It is used as default sort in Python, Java and maybe more languages. If you are using these languages, maybe it is best option in terms of your time and performance you will get.

In other case, merging sorted chunks can be done using many different strategies, whose performance differ mainly based on the data you have (number of chunks and sizes of chunks).

Besides mergesort approach mentioned in other answers there is a possibility to build heap. You will first fill heap with first elements of each chunk.
Whenever you pop an element from heap, you will replace it with next element from corresponding chunk. This given you O(n log k) complexity (n - size of array, k - number of chunks).

If you opt for mergesort approach, make sure, that you merge chunks, which are approximatelly equal in size. If you have one big chunk and repeatedly merge small chunks into it, you might end up with really big blowup in time complexity. Safest approach here is to always merge the smallest chunks (again you might have to use heap for tracking size of the chunks).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that an **MergeSort** could be the solution that fits your case scenario at best:

> `Basically any Merge sort algorithm can be summarized by:
>
> 1. Split the array in half
> 2. Sort the left half
> 3. Sort the right half
> 4. Merge the two halves together

However as you described your problem you kinda have this structure. 
So you could write an algorithm based on MergeSort that recursively merge your chunkcs of data and sort the result:
[image: MergeSort example]

Comment: The improvement to this algorithm is to store the min/max priority queue from few of the sub arrays, in this case you can merge more than one array at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You must be knowing about merge sort which uses divide and conquer paradigm.

Similar questions, go through these and you will get your answer: 
[Example 1](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-arrays/) 
[Example 2](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-linked-lists/)

Answer (score 0):

I have thought about the problem and came out with following generic solution in C++.

```
template<typename T>
struct Triplet
{
    T elm;
    size_t listIdx;
    size_t elmIdx;

    Triplet(T e, size_t ldx, size_t eIdx) : elm(e), listIdx(ldx), elmIdx(eIdx) {}

    bool operator<(const Triplet &trp) const {
        return elm < trp.elm;
    }
    bool operator>(const Triplet &trp) const {
        return elm > trp.elm;
    }

};

template<typename T>
vector<T> mergeSortedLists(const vector<vector<T>> &vec)
{
    vector<T> ret;
    priority_queue<Triplet<T>, vector<Triplet<T>>, std::greater<Triplet<T>>> pq;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        if (vec[i].size() > 0) {
            pq.push({ vec[i][0], i, 0 });
        }
    }
    while (!pq.empty()) {
        Triplet<T> trp = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        ret.push_back(trp.elm);
        if (trp.elmIdx < vec[trp.listIdx].size() - 1) {
            pq.push({ vec[trp.listIdx][trp.elmIdx + 1], trp.listIdx, trp.elmIdx + 1 });
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The idea is simple: create a min-heap (in this case priority queue with the smallest element on top). First fill the heap with firsts elements of each list, represented as triplets: the element, the index of the list containing the element ind the index of the element inside of the list.  Pop the top element, put it into solution vector, advance the element index one position and push the new triplet into the heap.

**The algorithm works with any number of presorted lists**, and the lists **must not be of the same size**. Here are some examples of usage:

```
int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> vint = { {1,3,5}, {2,4,6}, {3,5,7} };
    vector<int> resInt = mergeSortedLists(vint);
    vector<int> combinedInt = { 1,3,5,2,4,6,3,5,7 };
    std::sort(combinedInt.begin(), combinedInt.end());
    assert(resInt == combinedInt);

    vector<vector<string>> vstr = { {"abc"}, {"adef"}, {"ccfgt"}, {"aaabb"} };
    vector<string> resStr = mergeSortedLists(vstr);
    vector<string> combinedStr = { "abc", "adef", "ccfgt", "aaabb" };
    std::sort(combinedStr.begin(), combinedStr.end());
    assert(resStr == combinedStr);

    vector<vector<char>> vchar = { {'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d', 'e' }, {'b', 'd', 'f'}, {'e','f','g','h'} };
    vector<char> resChar = mergeSortedLists(vchar);
    vector<char> combinedChar = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' , 'b', 'd', 'f','e','f', 'g', 'h' };
    std::sort(combinedChar.begin(), combinedChar.end());
    assert(resChar == combinedChar);
}
```

The algorithm runs faster than "brute force" putting all elements into a single list and sorting them.
Let's assume we have m lists, every list of the size n. So, the "brute force" algorithm run time would be

```
O(m * n) + O(m * n * log(m * n)) = O(m * n * log(m * n))
```

The run time of the algorithm above is

```
O (m * n * log(m))
```

Here, the size of the heap is always <= m. O (m * n * log(m)) for pushing and popping elements from the heap.

The algorithm can be slightly improved as follows:

```
template<typename T>
vector<T> mergeSortedLists(const vector<vector<T>> &vec)
{
    vector<T> ret;
    priority_queue<Triplet<T>, vector<Triplet<T>>, std::greater<Triplet<T>>> pq;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        if (vec[i].size() > 0) {
            pq.push({ vec[i][0], i, 0 });
        }
    }
    while (!pq.empty()) {
        Triplet<T> trp = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        ret.push_back(trp.elm);
        while ((trp.elmIdx < vec[trp.listIdx].size() - 1) && (vec[trp.listIdx][trp.elmIdx + 1] == ret.back())) {
            ret.push_back(vec[trp.listIdx][trp.elmIdx + 1]);
            trp.elmIdx++;
        }
        if (trp.elmIdx < vec[trp.listIdx].size() - 1) {
            pq.push({ vec[trp.listIdx][trp.elmIdx + 1], trp.listIdx, trp.elmIdx + 1 });
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

My measurements on a Windows machine (compiled with MS Visual Studio) show following results:

```
10 x 100000 (10 presorted vectors each of size 100000 ):
Brute Force algorithm: 0.0407124 s
My algorithm: 0.030523 s

50 x 100000 :
Brute Force algorithm: 0.237032 s
My algorithm: 0.217482 s

100 x 100000:
Brute Force algorithm: 0.422206 s
My algorithm: 0.356308 s
```

In all cases I filled vectors with random integers between 0 and 100000
and used **exactly the same presorted lists for both algorithms**.

Comment: "After the `pq.pop();`, the new top of `pq` will be the runner-up: how about appending elements from `vec[trp.listIdx]` to the result while not greater?

Comment: Yes, thank you, the modification you proposed makes the algorithm a bit faster.